# How to find active directory group status

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I can find the status of active directory user using the below code.

```
var response = (SearchResponse)ldapConnection.SendRequest(userReq);

var result = response.Entries[0];
Convert.ToBoolean(
int.Parse(result.Attributes["useraccountcontrol"][0].ToString()) &
                                            0x0002)
```

While I am using for active directory groups, It is always returning null.

Can anyone suggest how to find active directory group status ?

Comment: What type of object is `result`?

Comment: I have edited my code.

Comment: Did you specify "useraccountcontrol" as one of the attributes in your SearchRequest object (userReq)? The search will only return the attributes you specify.